# Set collection fetch with a specific ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I need to create a collection but I need to fetch by this collection not by its url but a specific ajax call inside. It's possible?I'm trying to explain better:in normal case when fetch by a collection,the fetch use the url in collection but I need to use a results by an ajax call and not by url.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
headers: {'X-Parse-Application-Id':'qS0KLM***EM1tyhM9EEPiTS3VMk','X-Parse- 
REST-API-Key':'nh3eoUo9G8Df****vbF2gMhcKJIfIt1Gm'},
url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/",

data: 'where={"amici": 
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"g0fRKnrgZN"}}',//restituisce chi ha   
negli amici l'id objectId
//contentType: "application/json",

success: function(data) {
      console.log(data );

    },
    error: function(data) {

      console.log("ko" );
    }



});
```

I need to create my collection by a fetch based on this ajax call.

Comment: Can you provide us with some code so we can get a better sense of what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override any options of fetch call this way:

```
yourCollection.fetch({url: newUrl})
```

Or you can use construction like this:

```
yourCollection.fetch = function(options) {
    return this.constructor.__super__.fetch.call(this, _.extend({url: newUrl}, options));
};
```

if you want to override fetch call for `yourCollection` within the whole View, for example. Then in this View you will be able to use just `yourCollection.fetch()` without `newUrl` parameter.

Hope, it will be usefull for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1)** Override fetch in the current collection:

```
fetch: function(options) {
            // your extra code
            //..
            // maintain the return below if want to preserve the original fetch
            //return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
},
```

**Option 2)** If you want to use it for all of your collections:

Extend `Backbone.Collection` to a new object `YourCollection`, and override fetch in this new object. Now your new collections can extend YourCollection rather than `Backbone.Collection`

**PS** If you need to, you can also modify the ajax call:

```
    var ajax = $.ajax;

    $.ajax = function(url, options) {
       //your code
       return ajax.call(this, url, options);
    };
```

Comment: if I want return the ajax results?